# When to use three tables relation and when not?

Tags: php, sql

When exactly am i used to use the three tables `relation` method? I already understand we use it for Tags and multiple calls like

```
     1                   2                   3
[id  -  tag]      [post  -  tag]      [id    -   post]
[i   -   i ]      [ i    -   i ]      [i     -     i ]
[ii  -   ii]      [ ii   -   i ]      [ii    -     ii]
```

so when we have a post and want all his tags we use the `relation`, But lets say in a case i have table for posts and it is like this

```
[ id  -  username   -   post   -   content]
[ i   -      i      -     i    -       i  ]
[ ii  -      i      -     i    -       ii ]
[ iii -      i      -     i    -       iii]
```

and the user posted the same post 3 times with the same title, but different content, And i want to draft them for him, do i have to make a relation in this table to for 3 relation between the username and post? since they're repeated many times.

Comment: How could two "post"s be the same if they have different content and are created at different times?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Just to be drafted for all authors to see the duplicated posts, So they maybe find the other content mentions their topic in better way, so he just use the other author's post and edit it a little.